# Подскажите как правильно создать xml из строки

Tags: c#, xml

Хочу создать из строки xml файл с возможностью дописывания, но вылетает ошибка, что мол какой то символ нельзя использовать, пишет что "" недопустимо. Что не так я делаю? Мой код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "09.09.2018 18:24:56|Иван Иванов|9/9/2018 12:00:00 AM|2|Анна Каренина|DHL";
    string[] ss = s.Split('|');
    getXML(ss);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static void getXML(string[] mass)
{
    const string NAME_FILE = "test.xml";
    if (File.Exists(NAME_FILE))
    {
        XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Load(NAME_FILE);
        doc1.Root.Add(new XElement("Имя",
            new XElement("date", mass[0]),
            new XElement("Имя", mass[1]),
            new XElement("Выбранное время", mass[2]),
            new XElement("Количество", mass[3]),
            new XElement("Выбранный товар", mass[4]),
            new XElement("Доставка", mass[5])));
        doc1.Save(NAME_FILE);
    }
    else
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("Заказы"));
        doc.Root.Add(new XElement("Имя",mass[1],
            new XElement("date", mass[0]),
            new XElement("Имя", mass[1]),
            new XElement("Выбранное время", mass[2]),
            new XElement("Количество", mass[3]),
            new XElement("Выбранный товар", mass[4]),
            new XElement("Доставка", mass[5])));
        doc.Save(NAME_FILE);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас внутри ветвей `if` код почти полностью совпадает, `XDocument.Load`/`new XDocument` можно оставить, а всё остальное вынести за пределы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для преобразования произвольных строк в валидные xml-имена можно использовать метод [XmlConvert.EncodeName](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlconvert.encodename?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
new XElement(XmlConvert.EncodeName("Выбранное время"), mass[2]),
```

В данном случае получится строка:

```
Выбранное_x0020_время
```

Метод `XmlConvert.DecodeName` выполняет обратную операцию.

Answer (score 2):

Элементы (и атрибуты) XML не могут иметь имена, содержащие пробелы: `Выбранное время`, замените, например, на `ВыбранноеВремя` и код заработает (не забудьте также про `Выбранный товар`).